My postgres database startup has been running for almost 2 days+
I messed up my pgsql database by mistakenly deleting files on pg_wal, it resulted to a non-recoverable state (with no backups to restore with) so i decided to run the pg_resetwal.exe -f (considering the data loss).
After resetwal, I ran: postgres -D /u01/pgsql/15/data, and since wednesday (12/18/2024) and up to this date (12/20/2024) the startup is still running? Was this normal? How long does it usually take to finish starting-up? Or Should i terminate the running PID for the startup and rebuild the database from scratch?
Sample logs as of date:
2024-12-20 08:06:46.367 PST [826063] LOCATION:  LogCheckpointStart, xlog.c:6099
2024-12-20 08:06:46.477 PST [826063] LOG:  00000: checkpoint complete: wrote 2 buffers (0.0%); 0 WAL file(s) added, 0 removed, 1 recycled; write=0.102 s, sync=0.001 s, total=0.110 s; sync files=2, longest=0.001 s, average=0.001 s; distance=16380 kB, estimate=16383 kB
2024-12-20 08:06:46.477 PST [826063] LOCATION:  LogCheckpointEnd, xlog.c:6188


the startup is still running? Was this normal? - no. If what you mean is postgres started and is still running - then it looks like you simply started postgres but the process didn't daemonize (background) and your terminal is just the foreground instance of postgres running. If you have lost the data, it may be better to start over, wipe the data directory and reinitialize postgres to ensure there are no remnants in data that are causing problems. It would help to know what OS you are running.

Hi David, thank you for taking time on answering my question. My OS is   Oracle Linux Server 8.6, x86-64

Status showing as failed, even though it keeps generating archives and logs.
Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2024-12-20 07:42:52 PST; 57min ago
Docs: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/static/
Process: 916586 ExecStart=/usr/pgsql-15/bin/postmaster -D ${PGDATA} (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
Process: 916581 ExecStartPre=/usr/pgsql-15/bin/postgresql-15-check-db-dir ${PGDATA} (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
Main PID: 916586 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

A very simple to follow PostgreSQL setup is how I've always initialized postgres. Never had any issues. Since you are on Linux, albeit Oracle, you will have a similar init/setup. I don't know what init-system Oracle uses, whether SysV or systemd or something else, but the initialization should be the same. If you have remnants from your earlier setup in your data directory, that likely is the source of the current problems.

(with no backups to restore with) - if your data wasn't valuable enough to back up, then you might as well re-initialise as suggested by @DavidC.Rankin!

The status as reported by the OS package/service manager is often bogus.  Look in the PostgreSQL log file, or use pg_isready, or just try to connect (from a different tty) and see what happens.

The server is actually up and running. If it is performing checkpoints rather than restartpoints, PostgreSQL is done with recovery, and you can connect.
You should start the server with pg_ctl rather than postgres if you want to run it in the background.
